# How to check duplicates in two columns with JavaScript and by their values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of data like this:

```
var data = [
    // Columns
    ['Target ID', 'Source ID', 'Label'],

    // Key: 1
    [1, 2, 'String 1/2'],
    [1, 3, 'String 1/3'],
    [1, 4, 'String 1/4'],
    [1, 5, 'String 1/5'],

    // Key: 2
    [2, 1, 'String 2/1'],
    [2, 3, 'String 2/3'],
    [2, 4, 'String 2/4'],
    [2, 5, 'String 2/5'],

    // Key: 3
    [3, 1, 'String 3/1'],
    [3, 2, 'String 3/2'],
    [3, 4, 'String 3/4'],
    [3, 5, 'String 3/5']
]
```

As you can see, I have duplicate items in the array above, ie:

```
[1, 2, 'String 1/2']
```

And:

```
[2, 1, 'String 2/1']
```

I can't figure out the logic to remove those kind of duplicates.

All what I have achived so far is to remove duplicated items by first key value (since the array/data is created from a CSV), ie. `[1, 1, 'String 1/2']`.

Basically my question is: how to remove duplicated items from the array above?

---

**EDIT:** Better explanation of my problem.

The string at the index `2` in the array has nothing to do with anything - it's just a descriptor.

First item in the array is the key - in the examples I provided they are - `1, 2, 3` - thus, a second item is related to the key elsewhere in the array, thus, a relation between `1, 2` and `2, 1` is a duplicate - and I want those removed.

**EDIT 2:** Added the column item in the array above:

So, now I hope it's more clear -- first item in each array is the `Target ID`, second is the `Source ID` and the third one is not relavant at all.

My goal and need is to remove all items which already occur in the array, if the `Target ID === Source ID` in any of the previous arrays/items.

I have tried something dumb as:

```
var in_target = [];
var in_source = [];

var reformed_data = [];

for(var x in data) {
    var _target = data[x][0];
    var _source = data[x][1];

    if(in_target.indexOf( _target ) === -1) {
        if(in_source.indexOf( _source) === -1) {
            reformed_data.push( data );
        }
    }

    in_target.push( _target );
    in_source.push( _source );
}

console.log( reformed_data );
```

But is doesn't work and it's terribly slow, since I actually have a large piece of data.

Comment: `'String 1/2'` is equal to `'String 2/1'`...?

Comment: It is and I want all those items removed.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of a "duplicate" then. Apparently it's not simply "exact equality".

Comment: does the string correspond to the first two elements of the inner array?

Comment: English is not my primary, so bare with me. @NinaScholz string has nothing to do with it - it's just a descriptor. @deceze First item in the array is the key - in the examples I provided they are - 1, 2, 3 - thus, a second item is related to the key elsewhere in the array, thus, a relation between `1, 2` and `2, 1` is a duplicate - and I want those removed.

Comment: The basic approach is to destructure the data into a format that deduplicates itself, e.g. `o[1][2] = 'String 1/2';`. However, that apparently won't work with what you regard to be duplicates, so you'll have to clarify.

Comment: Won't you end up only with prime numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't figure out the logic to remove those kind of duplicates.

Try this approach

```js
var arr = [
    [1, 2, 'String 1/2'],
    [1, 3, 'String 1/3'],
    [1, 4, 'String 1/4'],
    [1, 5, 'String 1/5'],
    [2, 1, 'String 2/1'],
    [2, 3, 'String 2/3'],
    [2, 4, 'String 2/4'],
    [2, 5, 'String 2/5'],
    [3, 1, 'String 3/1'],
    [3, 2, 'String 3/2'],
    [3, 4, 'String 3/4'],
    [3, 5, 'String 3/5']
];
var map = {}; //initialize this map
var output = arr.filter( function(item){ 
  var key1 = item[0], key2 = item[1]; 
  map[key1] = map[key1] || {};  //create a map of map[1] for chain of 1
  map[key2] = map[key2] || {};  //create a map of map[2] for chain of 2
  map[key1][key2] = true;  //now mark the map[1][2] to true
  return !map[ key2 ][ key1 ] ;  //check if map[2][1] is not true
});
console.log( output );
```

Comment: Hm... helps, but I still get a lot of duplicated items in both directions. Only when I apply it to my large CSV/array data.

Comment: can you share that data so that I can test this logic with that data?

Comment: It's very large - might slow up your browser. https://gist.github.com/duvdevani/5673002d1bf157deb8ef1a9b908b1740

Comment: @Duvdevan on your data, how many rows should be returned? I am getting `output.length == 18336` while `data.length == 33672`

Comment: I'm always getting `22156`. Can you post a snippet of your tests?

Comment: @Duvdevan I am trying in browser's console, fiddle and snippets are breaking the browser. Not sure how I can share it.

Comment: Well post your code from your console, elsewhere - on gist, pastebin, etc.

Comment: @Duvdevan code is same only! Why would I post a different code here and run a different one on browser?

Comment: I had a mistake in my code/parser. Sorry! This actually works and thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

You could filter the data with a hash table with a sorted key.

```js
var data = [['1', '2', 'String 1/2'], ['1', '3', 'String 1/3'], ['1', '4', 'String 1/4'], ['1', '5', 'String 1/5'], ['2', '1', 'String 2/1'], ['2', '3', 'String 2/3'], ['2', '4', 'String 2/4'], ['2', '5', 'String 2/5'], ['3', '1', 'String 3/1'], ['3', '2', 'String 3/2'], ['3', '4', 'String 3/4'], ['3', '5', 'String 3/5']];

data = data.filter(function (a) {
    var key = a.slice(0, 2).sort().join('|');
    return !this[key] && (this[key] = true);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, but does not suffice.

Comment: I don't understand why you do a slice on an item? And after slicing, `TypeError: a.slice(...).sort is not a function` - is what we get.

Comment: it takes the first two elements of the array and returns a new array with the keys.

Comment: There was a mistake made by me in my parser. Your example works as well - thanks!